# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'XXXX' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub<XXXX>

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, signalr

I define my SignalR hub as

```
public class OutputMessages : Hub, IOutputMessages
{
       public OutputMessages(IHubContext<OutputMessages> hubContext, ILogger<OutputMessages> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
       {...}
       public void AdminMessages(string message, bool? consoleOnly)
       {...}
}
```

than inject this service to controller by this way

```
public class ApplicationAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    public ApplicationAPIController(ILogger<ApplicationAPIController> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IConfiguration Configuration, CoreObjectDumper.CoreObjectDumper dump, IHubContext<OutputMessages> _outputMessages)
    {...}
     ...
                    outputMessages.Clients.All.SendCoreAsync("AdminMessages", new object[] { "hello" });
}
```

all compile and working fine, no exception, even I see connection in OutputMessages, except main future of SignalR - client not receiving message. And, of course, I don't see in controller my typed method AdminMessages of Hub.

If I try inject to controller my Hub service as typed class

```
        public ApplicationAPIController(ILogger<ApplicationAPIController> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IConfiguration Configuration, CoreObjectDumper.CoreObjectDumper dump, IHubContext<OutputMessages, **IOutputMessages**> _outputMessages)
```

but receive strange message from compiler

*The type 'OutputMessages' cannot be used as type parameter 'THub' in the generic type or method 'IHubContext<THub, T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'OutputMessages' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub<IOutputMessages>'.*

Comment: Show us how you are injecting everything

Answer (score 1):

Your typed hub need to be declared like this:

```cs
public class OutputMessages : Hub<IOutputMessages>
{
       public void AdminMessages(string message, bool? consoleOnly)
       {...}
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#strongly-typed-hubs).

To inject the `Logger` and `ApplicationDbContext` just use DI.

Comment: if  I define hub as OutputMessages : Hub<IOutputMessages> (exactly follow microsoft rules in your link) compilation is good, but in run-time I receive error - Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub`1[IOutputMessages]' while attempting to activate 'OutputMessages'. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

Comment: Maybe it is because you are passing the constructor in to the hub. Why you just not resolve the `ILogger` and the `ApplicationDbContext ` out of DI?